# Saber si python esta instalado con batch o C++

Tags: python, python-3.x, c++, batch, python-3.7

Quiero saber si python esta instalado en el sistema mediante batch, o bien C++. Digo lo de estos dos lenguajes porque se pueden ejecutar sin necesidad de tener ningun compilador instalado, ya se en el .bat o en el .exe que genera C++.
Esto es lo que he intentado, pero en la primera linea de codigo abre el python en vez e seguir hacia abajo. Como puedo hacer para que compruebe la version de python y simplemente continue hacia abajo. Si esta instalado se cierre la aplicacion y si no esta instalado lo instale? Gracias

```
@echo off

python --version

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
    echo "Python isn't installed. You can do it here"
    echo ""
    set /p installer= Do you want to installed? It is necessary to run the script 

    IF %INSTALLER% == yes (GOTO INSTALL_PYTHON) ELSE (GOTO EXIT)

        :INSTALL_PYTHON
        START https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3.exe

        :EXIT
        exit

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0
    echo "Python is installed on your system"
    echo "Checking the other dependencies"
    python ./requirements.py

    cls
    echo "All is ready"
    pause
    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar el siguiente ejemplo para comprobar versión desde un script batch (.bat) y me funciona correctamente.

La sentencia `python --version` visualiza la versión y continúa la ejecución del script batch adecuadamente. Y la ejecución de procedimiento python dentro del batch igual, se ejecuta y se devuelve el control satisfactoriamente.

```
:: pyver.bat - [2020-04-30] - Comprobación versión Python.
@echo off

echo pyver.bat - Comprobación de versión de Python.
python --version

if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    echo pyver.bat - Python está instalado en el sistema.
    python ./test.py
) else (
    echo pyver.bat - No se encuentra Python
    echo pyver.bat - Descargue e instale https://www.python.org/downloads/
)
echo pyver.bat - Comprobación finalizada.
```

No sé muy bien donde se te está abriendo python en tu ejemplo, para que no pueda continuar el batch.

Saludos.